# Truffle doesn't migrate contract to Ropsten or Rinkeby via Infura (MetaMask)

Tags: solidity, truffle

In command line 'Network up to date'. Why?

I did everything how here http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/using-infura-custom-provider repeatedly. But doesn't migrate. And no errors. Just this 'Network up to date'.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Have you tried deleting your build folder?

Comment: Yes, before each compilation and migration I delete build folder.

Comment: Have you found a solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried  `truffle migrate --reset` ?

Comment: Important to note that `--network ropsten` or `--network rinkeby` should be added to this command.